# Defining WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN increases build times

Tags: c++, winapi

I am noticing something strange when working with the win32 api. I am working with a small project, and I tried adding a define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN right after where I include windows.h. Using the build time tracker in the build logs of VS 2013 RC, the build times are actually taking longer (10ms or so more) with define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN enabled. Am I defining WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN in the right place? Is the time spent running the preprcessor defines shorter than the time than just looking at them? If so, at what size of a project should you define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN? Thanks for the help!

**Update**: I chaged my define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN to before incuding windows.h, as advised, and it gave me a even larger performace impact. It cost me 260 ms in build time.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/30/9929944.aspx

Comment: Personally, I consider WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN an anachronism from the early 90s when a big hard drive was 25 MB and a fast processor was 33 MHz.  You could build huge projects for the rest of your life with that option and never regain the time you spent asking this question.

Comment: Okay, I defined WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before windows.h and had another big surprise. It added 260 ms to the build of my project.

Comment: If you ate going to include header files that WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN excludes, then you're working at cross-purposes since you are creating more work. The precompiled header won't have the header file so you have to pay the full parsing cost. (You are using precompiled headers, right?)

Comment: Yes I am. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, 10ms build time increase in a process that starts programs (compiler & linker) and does a lot of I/O (reading files) is not significant.

Next, you need to define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` *before* you `#include <Windows.h>`.  You may even want to define it in your project settings to ensure all files get the same definition of `Windows.h`.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to go BEFORE you include `windows.h`.

This constant removes extra headers from `windows.h`. If you define it after the `#include` then it will have no effect.